# CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to build a form using Razor template engine with ASP.NET MVC 5.

I have the following encapsulated call which I pass to the main view

```
public class ManagePresenter
{

    public ActionFormViewModel ActionForm { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have this view

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Manage", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-inline", Id = "ManageEmployeeForm" }))
{

    Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ActionForm.From);
    Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ActionForm.To);

    <div class="form-group">

    @{
        Html.LabelFor(m => m.ActionForm.UserId, new { @class = "sr-only" });
        Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ActionForm.UserId, Model.Users, new { @Class = "form-control" });
        Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ActionForm.UserId);
    }

    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <label>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ActionForm.ShowAlternateEntries, new { Title = "Alternate entries are entries from the telephony system that will help you compare against manual entries" })
            </label>
        </label>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="ManageEmployeeGetTime">View Records</button>

}
```

but every time I run my application I get the following error

> CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'
>   does not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor' and the best
>   extension method overload
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>,
>   object)' has some invalid arguments

What could be causing this error? `Model.Users` is a `List<SelectListItem>`

What am I missing here?

Comment: @JamesP please, show the basis for your statement, because all definitions of `DropDownListFor` I found accept `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

Comment: wild guess, are you sure you are not mixing MVC versions? Maybe `SelectListItem` in the model is from a different version of MVC?

Comment: @kiziu yes I am sure. infactI am using the something in a different view just with a different database and it is working fine.

Comment: The code you have shown will not even generate any html. You cannot the `HtmlHelper` methods inside a `@{ .. }` block without the preceeding `@Html......` Your code needs to be `<div class="form-group">@Html.LabelFor(...) @Html.DropDownListFor(...) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(...) </div>`

Comment: Similarly, your `Html.AntiForgeryToken();` needs to be `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` (and ditto for the hidden inputs

Comment: The only reasonable explanation is that you have mistakenly included the wrong assembly and your using `System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem` (or you have created your own class) instead of the required `System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem`

Comment: @StephenMuecke you are absolutely correct. That was the issue indeed. Please post an answer and I will gladly accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means (in your case) that one of the arguments of your `DropDownListFor()` method is invalid, and logically this can only be the 2nd parameter (for `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`).

You have claimed that the model contains a property `public List<SelectListItem> Users { get; set; }` so either you have created you own class named `SelectListItem` or you have included a reference to `System.Web.WebPages.Html` and are using the `SelectListItem` class of that assembly rather than the `SelectListItem` class of `System.Web.Mvc`.

Generally, you should not need `System.Web.WebPages.Html`, but if for some reason you do, then use the fully qualified name of class in you model

```
public List<System.Web.Mv.SelectListItem> Users { get; set; }
```

As a side note, your view will not generate any form controls (except the ckeckbox and submit button). Your have not prefixed the `HtmlHelper` methods with `@` which means the method will be executed, but it results will not be output in the view. You need to change the view to

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Manage", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-inline", Id = "ManageEmployeeForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ActionForm.From);
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ActionForm.To);
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ActionForm.UserId, new { @class = "sr-only" });
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ActionForm.UserId, Model.Users, new { @class = "form-control" });
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ActionForm.UserId);
    </div>
    ....
```